# Delete nlog files after one month of time

Tags: .net, nlog

I want to delete the nlog files after one month time. I add the following configurations to my nlog config file

```
<targets>
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
    layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" 
    fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" 
    archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/log.{#}.txt"
    archiveEvery="Month"
    archiveNumbering="Rolling"
    maxArchiveFiles="7"
    concurrentWrites="true" />
</targets>
```

But the files which are older than one month is still exists in my nlog folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is set up to start a new log file every month and `maxArchiveFiles` is set to 7, so the oldest archive will be deleted after 7 months. One option would be to change `maxArchiveFiles` to 1.